# Regextract between quotes include commas

Tags: regex, spreadsheet

I have question about regextract text between quotes in Google Sheets like this :

[MY SAMPLE SHEETS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vaOvncXwsBBI5vKWpldL5FdZSE-mdFjsFY3iKFm4IuI/edit#gid=0)

I am able to extract text between quotes, but when it has commas inside quotes, the formula didn't work.

Example : in Column A I had ["Apple","Orange","Banana"] its work fine
but when it contains commas like this > ["Apple","Milks, Breads & Vitamins"] it suddenly won't work

this is my formula :

```
=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract( A2, rept( ".*?""(.+?)""", len(regexreplace(A2, "[^,]", "")) + 1 ) ) ) )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why doesn't work your RegExp. It looks quite well. Probably there is some obscured rule for commas in this context.

Here is working variant:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract( B2:B, rept( ".*?""(.+?)""", len(regexreplace(B2:B, "[^""]", ""))/2 ) ) ) )
```

It counts quotes instead of commas.

[image]

You didn't provide expected result. So, I don't know what exactly you need.

Comment: I'm glad. I got an idea why it didn't work. The second RegEx counted all commas. But it should count only the comas outside quotes. So it returned 2 instead of 1 for the third row.

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
=arrayformula(iferror(split(substitute(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(\[|\])",""),"""",""),",")))
```